# Error using Soap Client in Magento

Tags: magento-1.9, soap-api-v2

Hi there i am facing the following error when trying to test whether soap client is working or not:

```
XML Parsing Error: mismatched tag. Expected: </schema>.
Location: http://localhost/magento/index.php/api/?wsdl=1
Line Number 13, Column 15:            </complexType
```

i am hitting the following url to reach out to the wsdl

http://localhost/magento/index.php/api/?wsdl=1

i have started working with magento and trying to access its webservice.

Comment: Did you try other URL's also? Is Url rewriting activated? Do you want to work with SOAP API v1 or v2? v1 URLs: http://magentohost/api/?wsdl or http://magentohost/api/soap/?wsdl v2 URL: http://magentohost/api/v2_soap?wsdl=1

Comment: i am working with SOAP API v2

Comment: Then you should try it with `http://localhost/magento/index.php/api/v2_soap?wsdl=1` (with or without index.php)

Comment: Check out the Magento SOAP API introduction: http://www.magentocommerce.com/api/soap/introduction.html

Comment: Great! I've added my comment as answer below. You can resolve the issue by accepting the answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments above:

The right URL to use with SOAPv2 API is:

```
http://localhost/magento/index.php/api/v2_soap?wsdl=1
```

(with or without index.php)

Further information on the SOAP API usage can be found in the Magento SOAP API introduction: 
http://magentocommerce.com/api/soap/introduction.html

Comment: Hi ANNA can you suggest whether to user REST API or the SOAP API for the development of magento mobile application

Comment: That's a different question, check out this one: http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/71534/which-api-method-is-best-for-apps?stw=2

Comment: Also this one on performance: http://magento.stackexchange.com/a/54476/231